# Add Thousand Separator when already using ToString for decimals in c#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, formatting, tostring

I'm doing my program on .net 7 using entity framework.

I need to format my prices like this : 1'234.56
However, they're appearing like this : 1234.56

```
f.Price.ToString("0.00");
```

The problem is that as you can see, i'm already using ToString function to round decimals to 2 after the dot.

I know I could use .ToString("N"); to format it, but i don't know how I could use both in a single ToString, my attempts were all ending by problems and the application not starting anymore.

Does anyone knows how I could format my prices with a thousand separator + only 2 decimals ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .NET 7 you can use `ToString("N2")`

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var price = 12348888.56;     
        string formattedPrice = price.ToString("N2"); // Use "N" format specifier to add a thousand separator
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

> Refer the working code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EPEXc2)